# dynamically created angular material component's template renders to md pseudo checkbox regardless of what is my template

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, angular-material2, typescript2.0

Hy,

I create website using angular 4. I try to create component at runtime. The component has angular material tags in string, but only `md-pseudo-checkbox` renders regardless of what tags I use. I don't understand why exact this one is being rendered.
Material component I try to get be compiled is in the *a.component.ts* 
By the way, one import thing is that if I remove `imports:[MaterialModule]` from *a.component.ts*then console says

```
Template parse errors:
'md-card-title' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-card-title' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-card-title' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message
```

So, does that mean that it is not possible to create angular material components dynamically?

**app.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [

        TreeviewModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule,
        MaterialModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', component: aboutComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'about', component: aboutComponent }


        ]
            ,            { useHash: true }
        ),
        TranslateModule.forRoot({

            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps:[Http]
            }

        }),


        Ng2FilterPipeModule,
        LoadingModule.forRoot({
            animationType: ANIMATION_TYPES.threeBounce,
            backdropBackgroundColour: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
            backdropBorderRadius: '4px',
            primaryColour: '#0000ff',
            secondaryColour: '#0000ff',
            tertiaryColour: '#0000ff'
        })
        ,
        BusyModule
        , BrowserAnimationsModule
        ,OTFModule

    ],


    declarations: [AppComponent, DclWrapper, SanitizeDirective, aboutComponent, LibComponent,  Menu, ReplacePipeComponent, OrderPipeComponent, aboutComponentLoader],

    bootstrap: [AppComponent]


})
```

**about.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild,ViewContainerRef,Compiler,Injector,NgModuleRef,AfterViewInit,NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpService } from '../servizai/http.service.component';
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies';
import { MaterialModule,MdCard,MdCardModule,MdCardContent } from "@angular/material";
import * as GLOBALUS from '../globalus/globalus';

import {Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { List } from 'linqts';

import { MdMenuModule } from '@angular/material';


import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';








@Component({

    templateUrl: '../../app/templates/about2.component.html',

    selector: 'about',
    providers: [HttpService],

    styles: [`
  .titel {text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #00467f;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}
`] 

})

export class aboutComponent implements OnInit {

    public puslHTML: any;

    public loading = false;



    busy: Subscription;


    constructor(private http: HttpService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer,

        private _compiler: Compiler,
        private _injector: Injector,
        private _m: NgModuleRef<any>

        ) {

    }



    ngOnInit(): void {



    }




}
```

**about.component.html**:

```
<div class="my-container">
    <ngx-loading [show]="loading" [config]="{ backdropBorderRadius: '10px' }"></ngx-loading>
</div>
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around start" fxLayoutGap="2%" style="background-color:#e8e8e8;padding:2%;">

   <otf-a-component></otf-a-component>
</div>
```

**a.component.ts**:

```
import { Compiler, Component, Injector, NgModule, NgModuleRef, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";
import { MaterialModule} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'otf-a-component',
    template: 'I am A component that inserts dynamic B component below: <div #vc></div>'
})

export class OTFAComponent {
    @ViewChild('vc', { read: ViewContainerRef }) _container: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(private _compiler: Compiler,
        private _injector: Injector,
        private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const template = `<md-card class="example-card">
  <md-card-header>
    <div md-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
    <md-card-title>Shiba Inu</md-card-title>
    <md-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</md-card-subtitle>
  </md-card-header>
  <img md-card-image src="assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg">
  <md-card-content>
    <p>
      The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
      A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
      bred for hunting.
    </p>
  </md-card-content>
  <md-card-actions>
    <button md-button>LIKE</button>
    <button md-button>SHARE</button>
  </md-card-actions>
</md-card>`;

        const tmpCmp = Component({ template: template })(class {
        });
        const tmpModule = NgModule({imports:[MaterialModule], declarations: [tmpCmp] })(class {
        });

        this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
            .then((factories) => {
                const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
                const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
                cmpRef.instance.name = 'B component';
                this._container.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
            })
    }
}
```

**otf.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { OTFAComponent } from "./a.component";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [OTFAComponent],
    entryComponents: [OTFAComponent],
    exports: [OTFAComponent]
})

export class OTFModule {

}
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "bus-vgtub",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "BUS",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "test": "karma start",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "vgtub",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "angular2-busy": "^2.0.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng-dynamic-component": "^1.0.8",
    "ng-pipes": "^0.1.2",
    "ng2-cookies": "^1.0.6",
    "ng2-filter-pipe": "^0.1.10",
    "ngx-loading": "^1.0.5",
    "ngx-treeview": "0.0.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "tslib": "^1.7.1",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.64",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "delegated-events": "^1.0.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "html": "^1.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "linqts": "^1.8.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "ng-dynamic": "^3.0.2",
    "ngx-dynamic-template": "^2.1.24",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "typescript-collections": "^1.2.3",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Comment: _does that mean that it is not possible to create angular material components dynamically_ - where you create them dynamically?

Comment: Id suggest to use `ngx-pipes` instead of `ng-pipes`

Answer (score 0):

Add the MdCardModule to your entry point in this case the app.module.ts

**app.module.ts**

```
import {MdCardModule} from "@angular/material";

@NgModule({
    imports: [MdCardModule]
})
```

afterwards you can use the material card component like in the [AngularMaterial Doku](https://material.angular.io/components/card/examples)

Comment: I tried. It didn't work. But I inserted `MdCardModule` to `imports` of component I try to create on the fly and it started to "draw" the md-card and now unwanted checkbox is gone. And it is great. So thank you for the hint. But now the question is how  to "draw" the rest (content,  etc) as now I see only shadows of card with white content.

Comment: So the [example](https://material.angular.io/components/card/examples) is not working?

Comment: I see only card's shadows. There is no content. It is white. Btw, I tried to remove everything a leave just say `md-card-contet` just to make sure how it works and the result is the same. I just wonder whether application takes the note that I am asking for `md-card` with content or it is just creates the emtpy card.

Comment: @AmoT Remove all included Material Modules include in your components its enough if you include the Module once in the "app.module.ts".
e.x. remove "import { MaterialModule,MdCard,MdCardModule ..." from your about.component.ts

Comment: if I include `MaterialModule,MdCardModule` to "app.module.ts" and remove all `import`s from "a.component.ts" then I get error `Template parse errors: 'md-card-title' is not a known element`

Comment: Remove MaterialModule you dont need to include that just include what u are using MdCardModule should be enough to be able to use md-card, md-card-conten and so on... and keep every included module in app-module.ts

Comment: if I leave only `MdCardModule` in "app.module.ts" and with no `import`s in "a.component.ts" then I get two problems: website fonts changes (as I just  removed `MaterialModule`) and the next problem (again) `'md-card-title' is not a known element`.

Comment: sorry for late post but what do you mean by _and keep every included module in app-module.ts_ ? How to keep the component I want to create at runtime in app.module.ts if I can not import it and declare? There was an example that shows it is enough to `import` `OTFModule`. So I did that.